# Elance / UpWork proflie pages on resume?

Tags: resume

I've built up a decent profile and work history as a software developer on both Elance and now UpWork. Indeed, the client reviews alone trump anything I could possibly boast about myself, and my profile is doing a much better job of selling me than my resume ever could.

I want to ensure that recruiters (particularly the ultimate decision-makers) see these profiles at some point during the recruitment process.

What's the best / most subtle way to do this? I've created shortened URLs to my profile pages (e.g. http://bit.ly/MyUsername-Elance), and put them at the top of my resume. But based on what I've read, most people are advising against this. And of course on a printed resume, the URLs are

Comment: Note: I am referring to applying to full-time jobs, or any job outside of the freelance platforms.

Comment: This question belongs on The Workplace, and not here.

Comment: On The Workplace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unusual to have a section titled "References" on the last page of your resume, although for professionals it often will simply state "Available upon request" or similar.

You might try adding that section if you don't already have it and place the URL there along with some text along the lines of "Formal references available upon request, or see my client reviews here >>".